# Merging multiples Dataframes where some rows are not the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

so I have 5 dataframes of the top 80 rated players taken from FIFA 13-17 each containing a players name, rating and club. My end goal is to merge all of these datasets together so I can have a rating per player every year and a null value if they didn't make it. Obviously, some players are not in the top 80 every year ie: Retirement.
Heres a snippet of three of the dataframes.

FIFA18

`Name                 Overall   Club
0   Cristiano Ronaldo   94  Real Madrid CF
1   L. Messi            93  FC Barcelona
2   Neymar              92  FC Barcelona
3   L. Suárez           92  FC Barcelona
4   M. Neuer            92  FC Bayern Munich
5   De Gea              90  Manchester United
6   R. Lewandowski      90  FC Bayern Munich
7   J. Boateng          90  FC Bayern Munich
8   G. Bale             90  Real Madrid CF
9   Z. Ibrahimović      90  Manchester United
10  T. Courtois         89  Chelsea`

FIFA13

`Name                 Overall   Club
0   L. Messi            94  FC Barcelona
1   Cristiano Ronaldo   92  Real Madrid CF
2   F. Ribéry           90  FC Bayern Munich
3   Xavi                90  FC Barcelona
4   Iniesta             90  FC Barcelona
5   N. Vidić            89  Manchester United
6   W. Rooney           89  Manchester United
7   Casillas            89  Real Madrid CF
8   David Silva         88  Manchester City
9   Falcao              88  Atlético Madrid
10  Z. Ibrahimović      88  Paris Saint-Germain`

An example of where this occurs could be with N. Vidić who has since retired.

My goal table would be this

`Name                 FIFA17  FIA13     Club
0   Cristiano Ronaldo   94      92  Real Madrid CF
1   L. Messi            93      94  FC Barcelona
2   Neymar              92      83  FC Barcelona
3   L. Suárez           92      86  FC Barcelona
4   M. Neuer            92      87  FC Bayern Munich
5   De Gea              90      82  Manchester United
6   R. Lewandowski      90      80  FC Bayern Munich
7   J. Boateng          90      84  FC Bayern Munich
8   G. Bale             90      86  Real Madrid CF
9   Z. Ibrahimović      90      88  Manchester United
10  T. Courtois         89      83  Chelsea
11  F. Ribéry           86      90  FC Bayern Munich
12  Xavi                 0      90  FC Barcelona
13  Iniesta             88      90  FC Barcelona
14  N. Vidić             0      89  Manchester United
15  W. Rooney            0      89  Manchester United
16  Casillas             0      89  Real Madrid CF
17  David Silva         87      88  Manchester City
18  Falcao               0      88  Atlético Madrid`

I am new to python and pandas but I have tried use join and merge but it always seems to use the index of each table rather than unique names.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what should be the club value if player changes the club?

Comment: @akshay-nevrekar The most recent club ie: with Z. Ibrahimović: Manchester United

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way via `pd.concat` and `pivot_table`. It assumes you are able to put your dataframes in a dictionary, which can be of arbitrary length.

The solution also deals with multiple clubs, keeping the latest club only.

```
dfs = {13: df13, 18: df18}

df = pd.concat([dfs[k].assign(Year=k) for k in dfs])

club_map = df.sort_values('Year', ascending=False)\
             .drop_duplicates('Name')\
             .set_index('Name')['Club']

df['Club'] = df['Name'].map(club_map)

res = df.pivot_table(index=['Name', 'Club'], columns='Year',
                     values='Overall', aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)\
        .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis='columns')
```

**Result**

```
                 Name               Club  13  18
0            Casillas     Real Madrid CF  89   0
1   Cristiano Ronaldo     Real Madrid CF  92  94
2         David Silva    Manchester City  88   0
3              De Gea  Manchester United   0  90
4           F. Ribéry   FC Bayern Munich  90   0
5              Falcao    Atlético Madrid  88   0
6             G. Bale     Real Madrid CF   0  90
7             Iniesta       FC Barcelona  90   0
8          J. Boateng   FC Bayern Munich   0  90
9            L. Messi       FC Barcelona  94  93
10          L. Suárez       FC Barcelona   0  92
11           M. Neuer   FC Bayern Munich   0  92
12           N. Vidić  Manchester United  89   0
13             Neymar       FC Barcelona   0  92
14     R. Lewandowski   FC Bayern Munich   0  90
15        T. Courtois            Chelsea   0  89
16          W. Rooney  Manchester United  89   0
17               Xavi       FC Barcelona  90   0
18     Z. Ibrahimović  Manchester United  88  90
```

Comment: I tried this @jpp and altered it to my database rather than outputting the two columns 13 and 18 it outputs a column year and fills it with 13/18

Comment: I updated my answer to deal with duplicate clubs. Sorry, I can't replicate your problem. My inputs are the 2 dataframes in your question, I don't have access to your database.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `MultiIndex` in columns with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), then replace `NaN`s by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), cast to `integer`s and last convert `MultiIndex` to columns by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
s1 = df1.drop_duplicates(['Name','Club']).set_index(['Name','Club'])['Overall']
s2 = df2.drop_duplicates(['Name','Club']).set_index(['Name','Club'])['Overall']
df = pd.concat([s2, s1], axis=1, keys=('FIFA13','FIFA18')).fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
print (df)
                 Name                 Club  FIFA13  FIFA18
0            Casillas       Real Madrid CF      89       0
1   Cristiano Ronaldo       Real Madrid CF      92      94
2         David Silva      Manchester City      88       0
3              De Gea    Manchester United       0      90
4           F. Ribéry     FC Bayern Munich      90       0
5              Falcao      Atlético Madrid      88       0
6             G. Bale       Real Madrid CF       0      90
7             Iniesta         FC Barcelona      90       0
8          J. Boateng     FC Bayern Munich       0      90
9            L. Messi         FC Barcelona      94      93
10          L. Suárez         FC Barcelona       0      92
11           M. Neuer     FC Bayern Munich       0      92
12           N. Vidić    Manchester United      89       0
13             Neymar         FC Barcelona       0      92
14     R. Lewandowski     FC Bayern Munich       0      90
15        T. Courtois             Chelsean       0      89
16          W. Rooney    Manchester United      89       0
17               Xavi         FC Barcelona      90       0
18     Z. Ibrahimović    Manchester United       0      90
19     Z. Ibrahimović  Paris Saint-Germain      88       0
```

If order is important solution is similar, only get unique pairs `Names` with `Club`, join together and remove duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
s1 = df1.drop_duplicates(['Name','Club']).set_index(['Name','Club'])['Overall']
s2 = df2.drop_duplicates(['Name','Club']).set_index(['Name','Club'])['Overall']
df = pd.concat([s2, s1], axis=1, keys=('FIFA13','FIFA18')).fillna(0).astype(int)

idx = pd.concat([df1[['Name','Club']], df2[['Name','Club']]]).drop_duplicates()
df = df.reindex(idx).reset_index().drop_duplicates('Name', keep='last')
print (df)
                 Name               Club  FIFA13  FIFA18
0            L. Messi       FC Barcelona      94      93
1   Cristiano Ronaldo     Real Madrid CF      92      94
2           F. Ribéry   FC Bayern Munich      90       0
3                Xavi       FC Barcelona      90       0
4             Iniesta       FC Barcelona      90       0
5            N. Vidić  Manchester United      89       0
6           W. Rooney  Manchester United      89       0
7            Casillas     Real Madrid CF      89       0
8         David Silva    Manchester City      88       0
9              Falcao    Atlético Madrid      88       0
11             Neymar       FC Barcelona       0      92
12          L. Suárez       FC Barcelona       0      92
13           M. Neuer   FC Bayern Munich       0      92
14             De Gea  Manchester United       0      90
15     R. Lewandowski   FC Bayern Munich       0      90
16         J. Boateng   FC Bayern Munich       0      90
17            G. Bale     Real Madrid CF       0      90
18     Z. Ibrahimović  Manchester United       0      90
19        T. Courtois           Chelsean       0      89
```

For general solution use `list comprehension`s:

```
dfs = [df2, df1]
names= ['FIFA13','FIFA18']
s = [x.drop_duplicates(['Name','Club']).set_index(['Name','Club'])['Overall'] for x in dfs]
df = pd.concat(s, axis=1, keys=(names)).fillna(0).astype(int)
s1 = [x[['Name','Club']] for x in dfs]
idx = pd.concat(s1).drop_duplicates()
df = df.reindex(idx).reset_index().drop_duplicates('Name', keep='last')
```